# Install previous version of MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, installation

Yo,

I've installed the brand new (updated) version of MonoTouch 5.4. And things not compile anymore in my code, call of ctors AVPLayerItem, AVAssetReader and AVAssetWritter... That I do not want to change the next few days. So my question: How to install back MonoTouch 5.3.6?

Cheers, Patrick

Comment: Also you should open a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com so it gets fixed ASAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support (support@xamarin.com) should be able to give you links to download previous beta versions.

If you want a stable version (MonoTouch 5.2.13 for instance), you can download it yourself from your [Xamarin Store](https://store.xamarin.com/account/Products) account.